# Check a column for all matches of specific text and apply timestamps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet containing several sheets, one of which is named Info. On this sheet, the cells in column L receive various words by means of a VLOOKUP which is pulling from other sources. I'm trying to figure out how to have the adjacent cell in column I receive an approximate timestamp when the cell in column L first receives the word 'START'.

I figure this should be doable by means of a trigger which runs every hour, checks column L for any cells with the word 'START', then inserts timestamps in column I's respective empty cells.

I've got this far with a script which works great for a single row when I have a single cell in column L selected, but how can I change this so it works regardless of where I am or what I am doing on the sheet?

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == 'Info' ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getValue() == 'START' ) {
    if( r.getColumn() == 12 )

      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -3);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

## **EDIT**

Thanks to Cooper this is what I ended up with. I made some edits due to the fact that the first 4 rows were headers containing formulas, and they were breaking whenever the function ran. This now prevents any VLOOKUPs from being overwritten, which seems to solve the issue.

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Info');
  var srg=sh.getRange(5,9,sh.getLastRow()-4);
  var sA=srg.getValues();
  var trg=sh.getRange(5,10,sh.getLastRow()-4);
  var tA=trg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
    if(sA[i][0]=='START' && tA[i][0]=='') {
      tA[i][0]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    }
  }
  trg.setValues(tA);
}
```

Comment: Why not use an onEdit trigger and check if the value contains start? This way you will get an exact time stamp

Comment: If the change is not due to a user edit then onEdit() doesn't fire.

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet?

Comment: @Cooper [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PpcrFFmJOXNkAF4h9qXFpTD-HHnwL4SMRsvqU8efKW0/edit?usp=sharing) is the link, I had to remove a bunch of stuff due to confidentiality, but there's enough stuff there to show you what's going on. When you run the TIMESTAMP function you'll notice the formula errors and the extra rows at the bottom of the second sheet.

Comment: There is no sheet named 'Info' in your spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Info');
  var srg=sh.getRange(5,12,sh.getLastRow()-4,sh.getLastColumn());
  var sA=srg.getValues();
  var trg=sh.getRange(5,9,sh.getLastRow()-4,sh.getLastColumn());
  var tA=trg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
    if(sA[i][0]=='START' && tA[i][0]=='') {
      tA[i][0]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    }
  }
  trg.setValues(tA);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this to my sheet and thought it was working great at first, but I'm coming across some strange behaviour whenever this function runs. The first 4 rows on the Info sheet are my heading rows, and there are several arrayformulas and vlookups in there. They kept getting deleted and I could not figure out why, so I edited the script as you can see in my original post, but now my formulas all display '#REF!/result not expanded because data would be overwritten' once the function runs. What am I missing?

Comment: The third parameter in sheet.getRange() is number of rows which in this case in sheet.getLastRow()-4.

Comment: That stops adding 4 rows on the bottom, but it's still making my header formulas error out. Could it be because the function is making the data under them appear as actual text entries? If I delete them, the formulas work again, but only until the next time the function runs.

Comment: You didn't mention any formulas in the original question and I only use very basic formulas and the rest I do with code.  I almost never use onEdit() and I try to limit my use of server triggers. So what ever problems you have with formulas, you will have to solve them on your own.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, thank you for leading me to the solution with your answer. You are a Helpful Sort.